# Insert image through JSP

Tags: java, jsp

This is my JSP code to insert image into Oracle database but I am not getting any output. Variables are getting values but code is not properly running.

I have used the Blob datatype for image in my database.

This is my JSP page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="com.sun.xml.internal.bind.CycleRecoverable.Context"%>
<%@page import="java.io.InputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.io.FileInputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
FileInputStream fis = null;
String fname = request.getParameter("pic");
String s1 = request.getParameter("txt1");
String s2 = request.getParameter("txt2");
String s3 = request.getParameter("txt3");
String s4 = request.getParameter("txt4");
String s5 = request.getParameter("options");
String s6 = request.getParameter("rsn");

try {
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "ankit", "ankit27");
    File image= new File(fname);
    //Table name is EmpDetails.
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into EmpDetails values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    fis = new FileInputStream(image);
    pstmt.setBinaryStream(1, fis, fis.available());
    pstmt.setString(2, s1);
    pstmt.setString(3, s2);
    pstmt.setString(4, s3);
    pstmt.setString(5, s4);
    pstmt.setString(6, s5);
    pstmt.setString(7, s6);
    int count = pstmt.executeUpdate();
    if (count > 0) {
        out.println("insert successfully");
    } else { 
        out.println("not successfully");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
</body>
</html>
```

I am unable to get any output.

Comment: Have you tried bebugging your own code? You should do that before asking a question here, because you will easily find out why nothing is happening, and then you can fix it. To do this you can add lots of println calls all through your code, and it should be obvious what’s wrong. If you add `out.println("Test message");` to the start of your code, can you see the output? If you can see the output then try replacing `e.printStackTrace();` with `out.println(e.getMessage());`, because your code may be spitting out errors and you are just not seeing it.

Comment: 6 `?`  but `setString(7` are you sure? You should also close your `FileInputStream`

Comment: yes I have tried debugging Its correct till  File image= new File(fname);